# How to write eshell script?

Tags: emacs, eshell

there.
I'm new to eshell,and now i come to a problem that how can i script it.
i've tried
    (rm ~/somefile)
and it worked.so is every command like this?how should i write conditional code and loop?and what should i customize to make the system execute my script using eshell other than others ,like bash,by default?
*i'm not very good at english,and i hope you can understand what i mean.i'll also appreciate any correction to my english expression?*

Answer (score 7):

You can call any elisp command/function/operator from eshell; I suppose that means you can script it using elisp (See [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html)).  Example:

```
Welcome to the Emacs shell

~ $ (defun foo (n) (if (= 0 (mod n 2)) "Even." "Odd!"))
foo
~ $ foo 2
Even.
~ $ foo 3
Odd!
~ $
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting *that*, but am quite pleased to have learned it. +1